# Vector tiles support on keppler.gl

Tags: reactjs, kepler.gl

I am trying to use kepler as a viewer for my new application.
I’ve been scanning your redux app structure, so, I eventually realised there’s no easy way to create a custom reducer to load PBF vector tile layers, I’ve seen few commits working with pbf load on your git repositories so I’d wonder to know if there will be a future version supporting this functionality on kepler (deck already works with vector tiles), so in that case, if there is any release date for that.

Kind regards and thank you all.

Comment: Probably posted on the wrong medium.

Comment: where should I post this?

Comment: You seem to be addressing someone, probably the developer of the [kepler.gl](https://github.com/uber/kepler.gl) so most likely you need to open an issue there since you want info on the project.

Answer (score 0):

One solution to your problem could be to add the vector tile layers to your Kepler.gl viz as a map style from your custom tileset created using [Mapbox Studio](https://studio.mapbox.com/).  Once you create a style with a Mapbox GL Layer based on your custom tileset, you could use the custom Style URL as the map in your Kepler.gl viz.